# DataGridView in Check box column counting increment and discriminant?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I Want to just Count a Check box to present students i have a separate create function for (cell 7 check box ) check and unchecked and below to one label to show how many checked in check box. :(

```
Friend Function Re_chk(ByRef Dgv1 As DataGridView) As Boolean
    Re_chk = False
    Try
        Dim count1 As Integer = 1
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Dgv1.Rows
            If row.Cells(7).Value = True Then
                count1 += 1
            End If
        Next
        Student_Details.LblAttendceCont.Text = count1
        Re_chk = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMqiO.png

Comment: Try ignoring the false values since I'm guessing you only care about how many rows are checked.

Comment: There are on database to added record so ... , I separate chkbox function created

Comment: I want to simply counting a checkmarks in all record and increased and if unchecked so detriment count .

Comment: I want to simply to say increment and unchecked box so detriment count a value .

Comment: Please edit your question to describe in more detail of what you are looking for... I am unclear as to what you are asking

Comment: Also count1 one should be 0 not 1

Comment: I have starting 0 so first checkmark checked but value are display 0 so I have set 1

Comment: And if I unchecked so not changed  value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Friend Function Re_chk(ByRef Dgv1 As DataGridView) As Integer
Try
    Dim count1 As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Dgv1.Rows
        If row.Cells(7).Value = True Then
            count1 += 1
        End If
    Next
    Re_chk = count1
Catch ex As Exception
    Re_chk = 0
End Try
End Function
```

In your code call this function as below:-

```
Dim checkCounter as Integer
checkCounter = Re_chk(Dgv1)
Student_Details.LblAttendceCont.Text = checkCounter
```